# fetching data from the table

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, sum

Here am having two tables namely rent and student_hostel.the rent table looks like this

```
    id   date      stud_id  paid    balance

    18  10-2016       94    15000   15000
    19  10-2016       94    10000   5000
    20  10-2016       96    25000   5000
    21  10-2016       96    5000    0
```

my student_hostel table looks like this..

```
     id   first_name  last_name    stud_id     admit_date   hostel   class  room bed status

     94     ss        ff          PHBH00094     01-10-2016   12        16   115  501A    P
     96    maltu      uv          PHBH00096     01-10-2016   12        16   115  501C    p
```

In order to get the last inserted stud_id's balance  i used my code like this,

```
public function rent_outstanding($hos,$dt)
{
    $sql = "select s.stud_id ,s.admit_date ,s.class,first_name,sum(paid) as rt_paid,balance,rt.stud_id 
            from student_hostel s, rent rt  where s.id=rt.stud_id and hostel=? and rt.date=? 
            and rt.id = (select max(id) from rent r where r.stud_id = rt.stud_id and r.date='$dt') 
            and status!= 'G' and status!= 'R'  GROUP BY rt.stud_id";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql, array($hos, $dt));
    return $query;
}
```

the problem am facing here is i was not able to sum the values comes under the paid columns of same stud_id.
the output am getting is like this

```
SI.No   STUDENT ID   NAME    RENT    PAID    BALANCE
 1      PHBH00094     Ss    30000    10000    5000  
 2      PHBH00096    Maltu  30000     5000      0
```

the desired output i need to get is like this

```
SI.No   STUDENT ID   NAME    RENT    PAID    BALANCE
 1      PHBH00094     Ss    30000   25000     5000  
 2      PHBH00096    Maltu  30000   30000       0
```

Comment: any idea did anybody have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your final solved query is :

```
select s.stud_id ,s.admit_date ,s.class,first_name,sum(paid) as rt_paid, 
(select r.balance from rent r where r.stud_id = rt.stud_id and r.date='$dt' order by r.id desc limit 1) as balance ,rt.stud_id 
from student_hostel s join rent rt  on s.id=rt.stud_id where hostel=? and rt.date=? 
and status!= 'G' and status!= 'R'  GROUP BY s.stud_id
```

I have removed this line in your existing query  `rt.id = (select max(id) from rent r where r.stud_id = rt.stud_id and r.date='$dt')`

your `(select max(id) from rent r where r.stud_id = rt.stud_id and r.date='$dt')` means all time getting only one last row `rt.id` like `19 (for PHBH00094)` or `21 (for PHBH00096)`.
that's why you getting all time one last calculation.

Comment: i had given like this at the end `GROUP BY s.stud_id and rt.piad` at that time its getting but only one row is getting

Comment: can you share your 2 sql table with data?

Comment: yes i know. i want .sql file in your 2 table. it is possible?

Comment: how can i share it here don't know?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127145/discussion-between-mohammed-and-razibalmamun).

Comment: see then the problem is i wont get the correct balance the first id balance is showing here

Comment: what's the situation now?

Comment: now its getting like this...`SI.No   STUDENT ID   NAME    RENT    PAID    BALANCE
 1      PHBH00094     Ss    30000   25000     15000`